# How do I git-apply a patch to a previous revision?

Tags: git

Assume I have a branch with the following history:

```
A - B - C - D
```

Between B and C I modified a bunch of files including a particular file, call it foo.txt.

Then, on revision D, I modified that same file, foo.txt.

Meanwhile, a friend of mine took a snapshot of my directory at B and decided he would tweak foo.txt in some way.  Let's call that revision E.  If they were part of the same repository, they would look like this:

```
A - B - C - D
     \
      E
```

However, they're not so we just have A - B - C - D in my repository and then he sends me a patch for the differences between B and E.

Since I have messed with foo.txt as well, I can't just apply the patch directly to D, the context for the diff won't match, it's expecting me to be at or around B.

It seems like I would want to kind of create the hypothetical repository tree I mentioned above, then do a merge between D and E in this repository in order to play back my changes C and D together in the right order.

So my questions:

- Is this the most sensible way to apply changes based on historical 'baselines' ?
- Are there any drawbacks I'm not seeing?
- How does one accomplish this in git cleanly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're correct that you do want to take advantage of git's merge faculties. There are still a few possibilities. The most indicative of what actually happened is probably the merge, but a method resulting in a modified version of `E` applied on top of `D` isn't so bad either. Let's talk about how to do that!

If the patch contains the blobs it applies to (the output from `git format-patch` does), then `git am` is capable of attempting a three-way merge! The blob SHA1 records in a diff look like this:

```
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index ca1df77..2c98844 100644
```

If you've got that, you're in luck. Just use `git am --3way <patch>`. Unfortunately, `git am` does require the email-style header that format-patch produces, so if the patch came from `git diff` instead of `git format-patch`, you have to kludge a little. You can add it yourself:

```
From: Bobby Tables <bobby@drop.org>
Date: 2 Nov 2010
Subject: [PATCH] protect against injection attack

<original diff>
```

`git am` should be able to work with that, and if you don't get it all exactly how you wanted it, you can always `git commit --amend` to fix it. (You could also try using `git apply --build-fake-ancestor=foo.txt <patch>`, but it really doesn't work in a user-friendly way. I think tricking `git am` is easier.)

If the patch doesn't contain any blob SHA1s (i.e. it was created with diff, not a git command), again, tell your friend how to use git, and I'm pretty sure you can *still* kludge it. You know what version of foo.txt the patch is supposed to apply to! To get its SHA1 from commit B, use:

```
git ls-tree <SHA1 of B>:<directory containing foo.txt>
```

It'll be one of the blobs listed. (I know there's a direct way, but I just can't think of it right now.) You can then add a fake git diff header. Suppose its hash is abcdef12:

```
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index abcdef12..
```

Git doesn't actually need anything but that first hash; though the git diff output would have the final hash and a mode, `am` isn't looking for it, so you can get away with leaving it off. (And yes, I just tested this. I hadn't done this before!)

This will result in a history like `A - B - C - D - E'`, where `E'` is your friend's patch, but applied to `D`; it's a result of a three-way merge between the content in `D`, `B`, and your friend's patch.

Finally, if you don't want to muck around with any of that, you can do as you said:

```
git checkout -b bobby <SHA1 of B>
# apply the patch
git commit --author="Bobby Tables <bobby@drop.org>"
git checkout master
git merge bobby
# or `git cherry-pick bobby` to grab the single commit and apply to master
# or `git rebase bobby master` to rebase C and D onto B
```

Comment: would you mind checking my question [Inline Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832242/how-to-apply-a-patch-to-a-different-source-version) on git merging. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look around—I swear there must be a way to do this automagically in git, but for now your best bet is probably to do what you've said.

Assuming your commit at `B` has ID `12345...`:

```
$ git checkout 12345
Note: checking out '12345....'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. 
[...]
$ git checkout -b friends_change
$ git apply < patchfile.patch
$ git status
[... something interesting ...]
$ git commit -m "Applying friend's patches to foo"
$ git checkout master
$ git merge friends_change
```

Of course, you could rebase instead, if you haven't published history to anyone:

```
$ git rebase friends_change
```

This'll create a tree like this:

```
A - B - C - D (old master)
     \
      E - C' - D' (new master)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to this one, and these answers were very helpful in pointing me in the right direction.  However what I really wanted to end up with in my case was this:

```
A - B - E - C - D
```

First of all, none of these commits had been pushed anywhere yet, so rebasing was safe.  If the commits had already been pushed and therefore potentially distributed, I would not have attempted this.

Here's how I did it (substitute as appropriate for the variables in wedges):

```
git checkout -b temporary <B-sha1>^
git am <E-patchfile>
git log --oneline -1
```

Now copy-paste the SHA1 and commit message.

```
git checkout <orig-branch>
git rebase -i <B-sha1>^
```

Now, in the appropriate place (which should be line #2), add this line:

```
pick <E-sha1> <E-commit-msg>
```

Save, let the rebase do its thing, resolving any conflicts as you usually would.  Finally:

```
git branch -d temporary
```

Since the branch delete wouldn't leave your patch commit dangling, you don't need to use `git branch -D`, and using `-d` also provides a nice way to verify that you didn't screw up something.

Hopefully this is helpful for other folks in situations similar to mine.